# Parsing text file input into an array

Tags: java, parsing, sorting

I have a text file that contains Names followed by 11 integers. I need to parse these numbers into an Array with the largest of the 11 integers value stored in the dimension that represents that value (0-10).

I also need to maintain the integrity of the name.

for example:

Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215: I'm looking for output like Aaliyah [9], and 380 value stored in that element

```
Aaron 193 208 218 274 279 232 132 36 32 31 41
Abagail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 958
Abbey 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 451 428
Abbie 431 552 742 924 0 0 0 0 752 644 601
Abbigail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 953 562
Abby 0 0 0 0 0 906 782 548 233 211 209
Abdiel 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 925 721
Abdul 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 903 0 0 0
Abdullah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1000 863
Abe 248 328 532 764 733 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

this is the code I have thus far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Names
{
    private static String name = "bb";
    private static int [] yearRank;
    private static boolean match;

        public static void main( String[] args)
        {
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("names.txt");
            try
            {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
                while (input.hasNext())
                {
                    String num = input.nextLine();
                    if(match = num.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i<11; i++)
                        {

                            System.out.println(num);
                        }
                    }
                }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.format("File does not exist\n");
            }
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`num` does not change within your loop - if you know that spaces separate the different fields, you can do, for example (not tested):

```
String num = input.nextLine();
if(match = num.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
    String[] fields = num.split(" "); //split the line into an array, each item contains a field
    for (String field : fields) { //loop over the array
        System.out.println(field); //print each field
    }
}
```